# How can I get games to stop pausing automatically when the controller turns off?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I'm playing through Fable III as a good guy, so I need to amass a ton of cash. I own everything there is to own in Albion - now it's time to wait for those income payments to roll in. When my Xbox controller turns off after a period of inactivity, the game pauses and income stops coming in until I touch it again. This is not ideal.

Can I either

- Get the game or the Xbox to stop pausing when the controller goes to sleep; or
- Get the controller to stop going to sleep after a period of inactivity?

Comment: Funny.  I was just wishing a certain game *would* pause when the controller turns off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't any way to keep the game from pausing when your controller shuts off. However, there *is* a way to keep the controller from turning off. Sadly, you need either a wired controller, or the Play 'n Charge Kit.

[image]

By connecting the controller via the USB port on your Xbox, it will keep the controller from powering off, allowing you to rake in the digital dough.

Comment: Boo extra equipment! Oh well. For Albion!

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller While it is extra equipment, if you've been running off of batteries up til now, it's a very useful upgrade!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to shell out additional cash, and don't mind killing your batteries while the game runs, you can also rubber band the right analog stick around the side/rear of the controller.  This will keep input flowing to the game, and keep the controller on while you're not playing.

I say the "right analog stick" because in most games this will make you look around.  It's usually safe to have the camera spinning in circles while you're not actively playing the game, unlike some buttons/sticks.

I did a variation on this to get the "drive 194.7 miles" achievement in L.A. Noire.  By rubber banding the throttle and the left analog stick, I managed to drive in circles in an empty field for a few hours, thereby avoiding a long and boring tour of the city.

Comment: I tried doing this in Borderlands to get the 20,000 bullets fired for the quick XP boost, and while my guns continued firing, the controller still shut off. =(

Comment: I'd have to assume the batteries died in your controller, or something similar happened.  The controller itself has no way determine whether the input is being generated by you or the rubber band, so there's really no difference in keeping in on.

Comment: Ah! Gotta find a rubber band and try this out!